# Dijkstra’s algorithm to compute the shortest paths from a given source vertex s in O ((V+E) log W) time

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

G (V, E) is a weighted, directed graph with non negative weight function W : E -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4... W } where W is any non negative integer. I want to modify the Dijkstra’s algorithm to compute the shortest paths from a given source vertex s in O ((V+E) log W) time.

Comment: Use a `Priority queue` with `Min-heap` which gives the edge with minimum weight.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a standard Dijkstra's algorithm with a priority queue and change it a little bit:

1. We'll have a map from an int (a distance) to a vector to keep all vertices with the given distance.
2. We'll pop the element from the first vector to get the current vertex at each iteration and delete a key if the vector becomes empty.
3. We'll push an element to a corresponding vector when we add it to the queue.

There are at most `W + 1` different keys in the map at any point. Why? Let `v` be the current vertex and `d[v]` be its distance. All keys less than `d[v]` were deleted. Any undiscovered vertex is not in the map. For any discovered vertex `u` `d[u] <= d[v] + max_edge_lenght = d[v] + W`. Thus, any key in the map must be in the `[d[v], d[v] + W]` range.

The size of the map is `O(W)` so every operation with works in `O(log W)` time (pushing/popping an element from the vector is `O(1)`).

Of course, it's useful only as long as `W` is relatively small (otherwise, you can go with a standard `O((V + E) log V)` implementation).